# Inserting 100000 record in DB using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, sybase

I am insering 100000 record in sybase DB using Hibernate ...but its taking more than one hour....Have used hibernate batching still taking same time...is there any way to increase the performance...I want to save 100000 records in less than 10 mins...but not able to acheive this goal.

have set the hibernate_batch_size in config file.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}
```

is it possible to insert 100000 record in DB using hibernate. I am able to insert 20000 record in DB using Ibatis in 20 secs but hibernate taking hours for me

Answer (score 1):

If you are using id generator in your mapping then Hibernate silently disables `hibernate batch`. More info [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1006916) and in hibernate documentation chapter 4.

I would go for a [`Work`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/jdbc/Work.html) and `jdbc` with hibernate rather than objects. At least that way you could make comparisons on performance.

You are creating a `Customer` object, then when you persist it `session.save()` it might get to DB to obtain the ID. Then the customer is added to the `Hibernate session` (level 1 cache).

When you have created, persisted, added to the session 20 objects the `flush()` performs the actual insert. Then the cache is cleared. Those references are set to null and marked for collection. But depending on your `heap` distribution and gc settings those instances might be already promoted to the tenured space. Even if it is not, a minor gc will be performed.

One optimisation could be generate the customer ID in the java code. Another optimisation would be to use multithread, I would go for both.

The simplest way to generate the ID outside the DB to save a connection per `Customer` would be using an `AtomicLong` (the type must be chosen depending on your ID column definition in `customer` table). If the batch is not a one time operation you must initialised with the highest ID in DB:

Then fire an [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html) with a batch and commit (`flush` and `clear`) after all are done. Repeating as many times as you need.

A naive example:

```
select max(id) from custormer;
```

Initialise the `AtomicLong` to that value and then use [`incrementAndGet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet%28%29) (which first increment and then return the updated value).

Using `AtomicLong` would enable your code to function in a multithread way.

The generate ID and multithreaded parallel execution would also work with the aforementioned `jdbc discrete work`.

NOTE: Concurrent execution take advantage on multi core environments, if your machine is a single core you won't be gaining much with multithread. Then you just could use a simple `int` to generate ids as everything happens serially.

Comment: How to generate the customer id in java code? I am using generator class in config file.

Comment: Hi @ssedano to be honest I am very new to Hibernate. So I would really appreciate if you can share some link for whatever you said above. Shall I use Work and creating Id at java side both or only one at a time.

Comment: Work is for discrete jdbc execution (this is the insert itself). I would first go for your current approach with generate ID and multithread. If this is still slow for your needs then try jdbc execution. But it is just my humble opinion.

Comment: In the config file I am pointin my id column to DB column. I am using generator class in config file. 

<id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="generator"/>
      </id>

I am not passing id....do I need to change in this config file also..can you please share one eg. if you have ever implemented or have any concrete link. Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Loading that many rows is a DBA type job, best done with command line tools/commands. I'm not familiar doth sybase, but there would be a command to load into a table directly from a csv file.

Java/hibernate is probably the worst tool for the job - memory and CPU heavy, and adding no value.

Comment: My requirement is to get 1 billion data from DB1 and using the java program load the all this data into other DB. I need to use Hibernate only for this.

Comment: @amiton2006 I can believe that you need to move a lit of data, but I don't believe the *method* of achieving this us part of the requirement, because it's insane. Go back to the person that asked to use hibernate and tell them it's a moronic idea and the task (moving huge data) is clearly a job for command line tools. It's not only faster to d excite, it's probably about 100 times less human (ie programming) effort. It's a no-brainer

Comment: QBohemian...if the data needs some kind of processing ...the I cant use command line tools.
Data from DB1--load in to java---processing----insert in to other DB is the flow.

Comment: Not necessarily true. What sort of processing are you talking about?

Comment: is it possible to insert 100000 record in DB using hibernate. I am able to insert 20000 record in DB using Ibatis in 20 secs but hibernate taking hours for me.

Comment: Hibernate is terribly heavy and unsuitable for large volumes. Instead, if you really need processing, use java to read in your file then write out the processed data into a new CSV file, then load that using database utilities.

Answer (score 0):

use a stateless session (which doesn't have a persistence context cache) :
This can speed up the process

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
   Item item = new Item(...);
   session.save(item);
   if ( i % 100 == 0 ) {
     session.flush();
     session.clear(); 
   }
}
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks I will try this. any idea how to generate id in java and isert that id in DB.